# How do I get something like an anonymous inner class in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

How do I define an anonymous inner class in Groovy? I saw references that they were supposed to be supported in Groovy 1.7 and I'm using 1.8.

```
 thread = process.consumeProcessOutput(
   new Appendable() {
     Appendable append(char c) {
       app1.append(c)
       app2.append(c)
       return this
     }

     Appendable append(CharSequence csq) {
       app1.append(csq)
       app2.append(csq)
       return this
     }

     Appendable append(CharSequence csq, int start, int end) {
       app1.append(csq, start, end)
       app2.append(csq, start, end)
       return this
     }
   })
```

I get an exception with this code:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.UNIXProcess.consumeProcessOutput() is applicable for argument types: (MyClass$1) values: [MyClass$1@19c8ef56]
```

Comment: well what type does consumeProcessOutput require? is it Appendable interface?

Comment: The term that describes your question is called a "closure" I think...

Comment: It accepts Appendable and OutputStream

Comment: How would a closure work in this case?

Comment: I figured out the problem: the correct method is consumeProcessOutputStream().

Answer (score 8):

This is a tricky case since the methods have to return the object itself as an `Appendable`, and has an overloaded method name that doesn't work well with groovy map to interface casting.  The simplest, clearest way is probably to just use an anonymous inner class, as you would in Java.  This requires a reasonably current version of groovy (1.7 or newer I think):

```
def testAppendable(Appendable appendable) {
    println "appendable = $appendable"
    appendable.append('a' as char).
               append('b' as char).
               append('c' as char)
}

testAppendable(new Appendable() {
    Appendable append(char c) {
        println "got $c"
        this
    }
    Appendable append(CharSequence csq) {
        this
    }
    Appendable append(CharSequence csq, int start, int end) {
        this
    }
    String toString() { "inner class appendable" }
});
```

Another alternative would be to use an `Expando` with closures.  It's a bit awkward since only one implementation per method name can be initialized in the constructor.  Note that any interface methods omitted are given a default implementation that throws an exception.

```
testAppendable(new Expando(
    append: { char c ->
        println "got $c"
        delegate as Appendable
    },
    toString: { ->
        "expando appendable"
    }
) as Appendable)
```

EDIT: Regarding your example, I don't see why it would fail.  My test is almost identical and works without any issues.  What does the signature of `process.consumeProcessOutput` look like?  Also, you can double check that `MyClass$1` implements `Appendable` by running `javap MyClass$1`.

Comment: +1 Added one [possible solution to doing it with a Map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895545/how-do-i-get-something-like-an-anonymous-inner-class-in-groovy/7900626#7900626), but I'd go your route if given a choice ;-)

Answer (score 4):

As an addition to [@ataylor's solution above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895545/how-do-i-get-something-like-an-anonymous-inner-class-in-groovy/7896353#7896353), it *is* possible to use the `Map as Appendable` notation, but it's a bit of a fudge:

Given the test function:

```
def testAppendable(Appendable appendable) {
    println "appendable = $appendable"
    appendable.append('a' as char).
               append("GROOVY",1,2).
               append("TIM")
}
```

We can construct our Appendable thusly:

```
def app
app = [ append:{ a, b=null, c=null ->
          if( a.grep( CharSequence ) ) a = a[ (b?:0)..<(c?:a.length()) ]
          println "Got $a"
          app
        } ] as Appendable
```

Then, executing

```
testAppendable( app )
```

Prints out

```
appendable = {append=ConsoleScript25$_run_closure1@173a30bd}
Got a
Got R
Got TIM
```

as expected...

Depending on the situation, I would tend to avoid doing it this way though, as the anonymous class route is far more readable ;-)

Answer (score 0):

this works in a recent indigo:

```
List l=new LinkedList() {
            {
                add(new Integer(1));
                add(new Integer(2));
            }
        };
println l
```

Answer (score 0):

Your anonymous class should be fine. Since all your methods just delegate to two other instances of `Appendable` you could also implement it like this:

```
final tee
tee = {
    final... args
->
    app1.append(*args)
    app2.append(*args)

    return tee
} as Appendable
```

The * operator causes Groovy to call `#append` with the contents of `args` as its arguments.

The `MissingMethodException` you're getting is because [`#consumeProcessOutput`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Process.html#consumeProcessOutput%28java.lang.Appendable,%20java.lang.Appendable%29) takes two arguments—one for STDOUT and one for STDERR. It also only reads enough from the output to prevent the process from blocking, so it's probably not what you want here. Try [`#waitForProcessOutput`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Process.html#waitForProcessOutput%28java.lang.Appendable,%20java.lang.Appendable%29) instead.

```
final app1 = new StringBuilder()
final app2 = new StringBuilder()

final tee
tee = {
    final... args
->
    app1.append(*args)
    app2.append(*args)

    return tee
} as Appendable

final cmd = 'ps a'
final p   = cmd.execute()

p.waitForProcessOutput tee, tee

println '*' * 80
println app1
println '*' * 80
println app2
```