# Java / Groovy code conversion

Tags: java, groovy

I am really stuck on a project  and would appreciate any one help ..
Trying to convert java code to groovy

Java code :

```
TypeReference<HashMap<String,Object>> typeRef = new TypeReference<HashMap<String,Object>>(){};
```

when i write the same thing in groovy :

```
TypeReference<HashMap<String,Object>> typeRef = new TypeReference<HashMap<String,Object>>(){};
```

i get the folowing exception :

```
 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [map type; class java.util.HashMap, [simple type, class java.lang.String] -> [simple type, class java.lang.Object]] from JSON String; no single-String constructor/factory method
```

now trust me i have tried every thing but its not working .. any kind of help would be appreciated . Please let me know how to do it.

Comment: [FYI](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7895545/2749470)

Comment: hello Bhargav TypeReference is a abstract class .. getting real migrane to get the stuff working .. need to get the stuff done today .. do you have any ideas ?

Comment: Could You provide a reproducible example?

Comment: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException sounds like the error happens somewhere else. Something like
    
    abstract class Foo{}
    def f = new Foo(){}

works just fine

Comment: Beyond that, does this have to be a blow-by-blow transliteration from Java to Groovy? Or do you have some leeway in accomplishing the the same blackbox program? To wit, is there a reason that you HAVE to use `Jackson`? Because I would recommend scrapping this approach altogether and rewriting using Groovy's native `JsonSlurper`/`JsonBuilder` combo.